# Prevent decreasing COM reference counter when application closes down

Tags: c#, com, reference, counter

I've created a UI front-end (called "B") using VC# for another application (let's call it "A").
B is a stand-alone EXE, which must be (due to some reasons) called by A. (DLL is not possible due to security policies.)

The current flow is:

1. Start A (which is acting as COM server).
2. Let A execute B using a system() call.
3. B creates a COM connection to A.
4. User closes B
5. A is closed, too. <<< THIS is the problem!

The desired flow is:

...(5) A is NOT closed.

As far as I found out, I believe that the reason for the undesired behaviour is that the COM reference counter is automatically decreased. Because B is using the existing A instance, the counter is previously 1, therefore decreased to 0, leading to the complete shutdown of A. (This is a real problem because the user may loose data in A at that moment.)

I already tried to influence the GC to keep A alive, but with no success.

The question is:

**How can I prevent the shutdown of A**, e.g., by avoiding the decrementing of the reference counter?

Comment: Sounds like the reference counting is wrong on the other end - if A has a reference to itself (1), then when B created a reference to it, it should have increased (2). Then, when B shut down, it's reference should properly be removed (1), but A should still have a reference to itself, if it needs it.

Comment: This may be the case, as the application A is "somehow" COM, but probably not "really".

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the com object in A you can do [Marshal.AddRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.addref%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on it to increment the ref counter, i.e. declare that A is using the COM object too.

Comment: After creating the A object with `instance = new A()`, the value of instance changes from NULL to 'System._ComObject' (according to the Debugger). When trying to add the reference: `IntPtr ptrDOORS = new IntPtr();
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(instance, ptrDOORS, true);
    Marshal.AddRef(ptrDOORS);` there is an error that `instance` is null.

Comment: You don't retrieve the IntPtr correctly. From Marshal.AddRef's documentation "You can call Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject, Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject, or Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject to obtain an IntPtr value that represents an IUnknown interface pointer."

Comment: Ah, GetUnknownForObject did the job.